# set environment variable with a "late binding value"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

During the image build, I am installing a "tool" to the image using the `RUN` command, and then I would like to set an environment variable permanently in the image based on the result of the installation.
I would like to have the same result as using the `ENV` keyword but I can not use this because I do not know the value in advance.

My solution works fine, but this looks like as a quick and dirty solution.

In the following code, please focus on the `JAVA_HOME` part.

**Dockerfile**

```
...
RUN set -ux; \
    apk add --no-cache java-cacerts openjdk17-jdk; \
    java -version; \
    javac -version; \
    export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java)))); \
    printf "%s" "$JAVA_HOME" > /tmp/JAVA_HOME; \ <-- ******* THIS LINE *******
    printf "export %s=\"%s\"\n" "JAVA_HOME" "$JAVA_HOME" >> /etc/profile
...
CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
...
export JAVA_HOME=$(cat /tmp/JAVA_HOME); \
...
```

This way I can set the environment variable dynamically and I can use it later from anywhere in the running container. But there must be a better solution.